# Prove $s_1 = 4, s_{n+1} = \sqrt{3s_n -2}$ Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that this sequence is convergent, as $n -> \infty$

> $s_1 = 4, s_{n+1} = \sqrt{3s_n -2}$

In our lecture, our teacher explained proving the above using the following theorem:

> A Monotone Bounded Sequence is convergent.

He guessed the bound of the sequence by solving:

> $s^2 = 3s-2$, which implied $s_{n+1} = s_n = \sqrt{3s_n -2} $

After solving, get $s = 1, 2$

And then he made the hypothesis that the sequence is bounded by 2. i.e. $s_n \geq 2$ and proved by induction.

My questions are:

1. How can we solve the equation $s_{n+1} = s_n = \sqrt{3s_n -2} $ to "guess" the bound? Isn't it contradicting?
2. After solving, why the hypothesis can be made by "bounded by 2"? Why 2? not 1 not 3?

**My teacher does not explain why he made this hypothesis. He just said that's how it is done. Therefore, I have the only option to ask this question in here.**

Comment: **Assuming** the sequence has a limit $s$, then by continuity (let $n$ go to infinity on both sides of the recurrence relation) $s$ must satisfy $s=\sqrt{3s-2}$. You most likely have $s_{n+1}\neq \sqrt{3s_n-2}$ for all $n$, but the *limit* (if it exists) will satisfy the equality. Now, by solving the equation, you can find the only *possible* value(s) of $s$, and that usually helps having an idea of **how** to prove that the sequence converges. But that is only the beginning...

Comment: @ClementC. I thought so, because as the limit goes on. The difference between the current term and the previous term is negligible. But why to guess the bound is 2? instead of 1? That's another solution though.

Comment: (so here you teacher got that the only *possible* values for the limit were $1$ and $2$. So looking at $s_1=4$ and $s_2=\sqrt{10} < 4$, it is "natural" to want to prove that $(s_n)_n$ is a monotone decreasing series that  is bounded below by its limit, $2$.)

Comment: @ClementC. I see. So because the sequence is decreasing at the first few terms, it is a natural guess that this is a decreasing sequence. There are two possible bounds, $1, 2$. Both of them might be the bounds, but 2 is the larger lower bound. So it is better to guess 2? Because if 2 is a lower bound, the "smaller lower bound" 1 is also a lower bound?

Comment: Sort of. This is only a heuristic, but once you find the possible values for the limit, you check for monotonicity, and then a natural guess is that the closest bound should probably work. (There are more involved ideas than this rule of thumb, where you can actually study the behavior, monotonicity, derivatives, of the function $f$ such that $s_{n+1}=f(s_{n})$; but for simple cases, computing the first few terms and using this rule of thumb is good enough.)

Comment: And nowadays, we can also even delegate this tedious task of computing the first few terms to [machines, or WolframAlpha](http://goo.gl/p3vTE0), so that it's becoming almost a painless task.

Comment: It is natural to hope that the sequence stays above $2$. And if we imagine that $s_n$ is above $2$, a glance at $\sqrt{3s_n-2}$ shows that $s_{n+1}$ is above $2$.

Comment: There is something interesting about $1$. It turns out that if $s_n$ is above $1$, then $s_{n+1}$ is above $1$. However, if $s_n$ happens to be near $1$ but a little above, like $1.01$, then $s_{n+1}$ is **bigger** than $s_n$. So if we stay above $1$, the limit, if it exists, cannot be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=\sqrt{3x-2}$ then the problem can be phrased as the recurrence $s_1=4$, $s_{n+1}=f(s_n)$. You can show that the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is bounded from below by $2$ by showing that if $x>2$ then $f(x)>2$ which is straightforward to check. You can show that the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is decreasing by showing that if $x>2$ then $f(x)<x$ which is also straightforward to check. Then by the monotone convergence theorem, $\{s_n\}$ converges to some $l\in[2,4]$. Additionally, since $f$ is continuous, you know that $l$ must be a fixed point of $f(x)$ (namely, $f(l)=l$). Then $l$ is either $1$ or $2$ but $l\in[2,4]$ ensures that $l=2$.

Solving the equation $f(x)=x$ finds the only possible values for the limit rather than just making a guess. Additionally, the bound of $2$ is something that is easy to check rather than an arbitrary hypothesis. More generally, you can determine whether $\{s_n\}$ is increasing or decreasing at any term by examining the difference $f(x)-x$.